# In this Code, I am getting this ZeroDivisionError : float modulo

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import itertools,math
from functools import reduce
import operator
b=[(1, 2, 9), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5)]
c= list(reduce(lambda x1,x2 : (float(x1)%math.sqrt(x1) and float(x2)%math.sqrt(x2)) , itertools.chain.from_iterable(b) ))
print(c)
```

In above code I am getting this error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: float modulo
```

My Expected output is:

```
[(1,2,9) ,(1,4,7)]
```

Here I want at least two perfect square elements from `b`.

In other words, I want `c` to be a list of each tuple in `b` that contains at least two perfect squares.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the expected output of that code?

Comment: I want at least two perfect square from b. So expected output is [(1,2,9), (1,4,7)]  .. sorry  @RoadRunner

Comment: @NisheetPatel Why not put that in the question?

Comment: What, like `[x for x in chain.from_iterable(b) if sqrt(x).is_integer()]`?  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with `reduce`

Comment: @NisheetPatel What does (1,2,9) and (1,4,7) have to do with perfect squares? Correct me if I am wrong, but perfect squares are a product of two equal integers: 1x1=1, 2x2=4, 3x3=9,...

Comment: Do you mean you want `c` to be a list of each tuple in `b` that contains at least two perfect squares? If that's the case, you don't want to use `chain.from_iterable`: that flattens the list of tuples. Your lambda doesn't do what you want, especially as an arg to `reduce`. And `reduce` is definitely not the right tool for this job.

Comment: @RoadRunner perfect square means : in (1,2,9) 1 is perfect square of 1 and 9 is perfect square of 3. and in (1,4,7) 1 is perfect square of 1 and 4 is perfect square of 2.

Comment: @PM2Ring you got right.

Comment: Ok! Give me a minute or two...

Comment: @PM2Ring Help me to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can solve this task by testing each item in each tuple and counting how many of those items are perfect squares. To determine if a number is a perfect square we use a helper function, `is_square`. To count the perfect squares we can use the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in.

```
from math import sqrt

def is_square(n):
    r = int(sqrt(n))
    return r * r == n

b = [(1, 2, 9), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5)]

c = [t for t in b if sum(is_square(u) for u in t) > 1]
print(c)
```

**output**

```
[(1, 2, 9), (1, 4, 7)]
```

`is_square(u)` returns `True` if `u` is a perfect square, and `False` if it's not. But `True` has a numeric value of 1, and `False` has a numeric value of 0. So `sum(is_square(u) for u in t)` adds up how many numbers in each tuple `t` are perfect squares.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the perfect squares with a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and retrieve the tuples that have atleast 2 perfect squares:

```
from math import sqrt
from collections import Counter

b = [(1, 2, 9), (1, 2, 9), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5)]

def perfect_square(n):
    return round(sqrt(n)) ** 2 == n

counts = Counter()
for i, tup in enumerate(b):
    for number in tup:
        if perfect_square(number):
            counts[i, tup] += 1

print([k for (_, k), v in counts.items() if v >= 2])
```

Which Outputs:

```
[(1, 2, 9), (1, 4, 7)]
```

**Note:** The above `Counter()` can also be written as:

```
counts = Counter((i, tup) for i, tup in enumerate(b) for number in tup if perfect_square(number))
```

But this becomes hard to read.

Comment: This might give surprising results if the input has repeated values, e.g. `b = [(1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 6)]`. I wonder if you could do something with `enumerate` so you could keep tuples distinct in the counter...